# How can I localize my Microsoft Teams bot welcome message?

Tags: microsoft-teams

When my bot is first installed on a Teams tenant, I appear to have no way of localizing that message. Most of my Teams app is currently localized by the browser locale available with all messages sent to it by users. 
However, when a bot is added to a team ([membersAdded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-notifications)), this locale information is not present.

Since I use graph for other app needs, I try to leverage the users [preferred language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0), but that cannot be done without first granting the app permissions to use graph. This means that the first time the bot is added to a team, it is never localized. After app permissions are granted by the user, future welcome messages in other teams are localized, but that also has the limitation that the locale used by the welcome message doesn't necessarily match the users current browser language preferences.

Is there another way to localize the welcome message the bot sends out?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known limitation currently. Bot has to wait for user to message. The message activity has clientInfo filled out in channelData with locale information.

Answer (score 0):

This is updated over the time and possible now. Use onInstallationUpdate method to get locale information and send bot welcome message based on that.
Doc reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/bot-basics?tabs=csharp#core-bot-framework-handlers